# ¿Cómo validar dimensiones y formato de una URL imagen en PHP?

Tags: php

Mi sistema no aloja imágenes en mi servidor, estoy usando la `API` de `imgur` por lo que solo válido que el campo imput dónde me inserta la URL de la imagen no esté vacío:

```
$CoverPage = $_POST["cover_page"];


if (empty($_POST['cover_page'])) {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["cover_page" =>"Por favor, agregue una portada a su reportaje."]]);
        exit;
    }
```

Pero necesito validar esa ruta de esa imagen, que tenga dimensiones mínimas `400x400`puede ser más pero no puede ser menos, formatos de imágenes permitidas `png, jpe, svg,` entre otras, esto es en caso de que se agregué otra ruta `URL` errónea.

URL imágen:

```
https://i.imgur.com/UkvbM34.jpg
```

> Es importante que en la validación de la imagen solo permita que la URL sea de imgur

```
if ( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
        $size = getimagesize( $file['tmp_name'] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar el formato:

```
$allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");

    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");
```

Aparte de verificar la extension, es recomendable verificar el tipo MIME:

```
$filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];     
if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
      //Aqui ya haces lo que necesites

    } else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
    }
```